# Unable to drop foreign key constraint

Tags: sql, sql-server, foreign-keys, constraints

Table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Visualization_ComponentLayouts]
(
    [ComponentLayoutId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ComponentId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [LayoutId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [UnitTypeId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ProjectId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [CreatedBy] [int] NULL,
    [ModifiedBy] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Visualization_ComponentLayouts] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ComponentLayoutId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Visualization_ComponentLayouts] WITH NOCHECK 
   ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_Visualization_ComponentLayouts_Visualization_ComponentInfo] 
   FOREIGN KEY([ComponentId])
   REFERENCES [dbo].[Visualization_ComponentInfo] ([ComponentId])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Visualization_ComponentLayouts] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Visualization_ComponentLayouts_Visualization_ComponentInfo]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Visualization_ComponentLayouts] WITH CHECK 
   ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_Visualization_ComponentLayouts_Visualization_Layouts] 
   FOREIGN KEY([LayoutId], [ProjectId])
   REFERENCES [dbo].[Visualization_Layouts] ([LayoutId], [ProjectId])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Visualization_ComponentLayouts] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Visualization_ComponentLayouts_Visualization_Layouts]
GO
```

Query to drop constraint:

```
ALTER TABLE Visualization_ComponentLayouts
DROP CONSTRAINT FK_Visualization_ComponentLayouts_Visualization_Layouts
```

Error I get when I execute above drop query:

> 'FK_Visualization_ComponentLayouts_Visualization_Layouts' is not a
>   constraint. Could not drop constraint. See previous errors.

In SQL Server Management Studio, in Object Explorer, when I expand the table node, and within that when I expand constraints node, no constraints are being listed there.

When I execute query : `EXEC sp_help 'Visualization_ComponentLayouts'`
I get following:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The foreign keys are listed under the `Keys` subnode of a table - not under `Constraints` (that only shows default and check constraints)

Comment: If you run this query: `select * from sys.foreign_keys where name = 'FK_Visualization_ComponentLayouts_Visualization_Layouts'` - do you get any results?

Comment: Or `EXEC sp_help 'Visualization_ComponentLayouts'` you can get all you need

Comment: @marc_s- I get 0 rows when I execute that query.

Comment: That means: there is no such foreign key - are you creating the foreign key in a wrong database or something?

Comment: @marc_s- oh, yah I was executing the query on wrong db, sorry very silly mistake.. executed now.